$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{\frac a{b(b+2c)}}\ge{\frac3{\sqrt[3]{3}}}$, for positive $a,b,c$ with $ab+bc+ca=3$

Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers satisfying $ab+bc+ca=3$. Prove that:
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{b(b+2c)}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{b}{c(c+2a)}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{c}{a(a+2b)}}\ge{\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{3}}}$$

I think the difficulty lies in the fact that it is not symmetrical. I tried using a holder, but the asymmetry causes a lot of difficulties. It also requires a lot of complicated calculations, so I want to find a better solution. I think it is possible to do the following:
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{b(b+2c)}}=\frac{a}{\sqrt[3]{ab(ab+2ac)}}=\frac{3\sqrt[3]{9}a}{3\sqrt[3]{3ab(ab+2ac)3}}\ge{\frac{3\sqrt[3]{9}a}{4ab+2ac+3}}$$
So we just need to prove that
$$\frac{a}{5ab+3ac+bc}+\frac{b}{5cb+3ba+ca}+\frac{c}{5ca+3cb+ab}\ge{\frac{1}{3}}$$
and I think it's correct because I tried substituting a few values ​​and it's correct, but I still haven't been able to prove it.

@Blue oh my bad, i have fix it, sorry very much

we can start by applying the AM-GM inequality$$\sqrt[3]{xyz} \le \frac{x+y+z}{3}. $$
$$x = \sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{b(b+2c)}}, y = \sqrt[3]{\frac{b}{c(c+2a)}}, z = \sqrt[3]{\frac{c}{a(a+2b)}}$$
with a bit of rearranging the problem simplifies to showing:
$$(a+2b)(b+2c)(c+2a) \ge 27 $$
(and I'll edit this answer once I've done this last step, or perhaps you'll beat me to it)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I took the asymmetry as referring to the fact that (a,b) are not related the same way as (a,c). If it truly is not a typo, then the question is false. We can try a = 0.99, b = 1, c = 1.01005.

@AdamDougall thank you, i have fix it
